# sms working perfectly on localhost but online it is not working

Tags: php, sms, runtime-error

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$adm=$_POST["admno"];
$phn=$_POST["phn1"];
include("model.php");
$db = new database;
$r=$db->register($adm);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{

if($row["phn_no1"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no2"]==$phn  || $row["phn_no3"]==$phn)
{
$formatted = "".substr($phn,6,10)." ";
$password = $formatted + $adm;
echo $password;
$db->setpassword($adm,$password);
$pre = 'Dear%20Parents,Your%20Password%20is%20';
$suf = '%20ThankYou.CV';
$sms = $pre.$password.$suf;

$ch = curl_init("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx
USERID=ID&PASSWORD=Pass$&SENDERID=SID&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Location:password.php?msg=new"); 

}
else
{
header("Location:register.php?msg=invalid");

}
}
}
?>
```

this code working perfectly on local host but online it takes too long to going next page and it is not sending sms to phone when online. although it is generating the password but not sending it to phone and taking too much time for generating it. but on local host it is sending msg.

Comment: I was having same issue but after a while it was working fine. So, just wait for a while and then try on the server.

Comment: `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` AFTER the **curl_exec($ch)** but before **curl_close($ch)**. Should give you some hints.

Comment: Try to eliminated the port number and try to send my SMS again. maybe be work for you.

Comment: When doing the CURL HTTP post you need to specify `CURLOPT_POST, true`..., because CURL's default http method is GET.

Comment: another maybe PHP version of localhost and server.

Comment: please elaborate where to put curl post command

Answer (score 0):

Try this before `curl_close` to find out the problem.

```
if( $result === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch).' '.curl_errno($ch);
}
```

Seem like connection timeout problem between your and sms's server.